# TDD with GNU ld (2.24 vs 2.26)

Tags: gcc, linker, ubuntu-14.04, ld, ubuntu-16.04

I recently moved from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04 for working on code. This moved me from GCC 4.8.4/GNU ld 2.24 to GCC 5.3.1/GNU ld 2.26.

I've been writing test cases for code and someone decided to override the default time() function for testing but linking behavior seems to have changed between these two releases. Example code follows:

```
nothing.c:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
void nothing( )
{
    printf( "%lld\n", (long long)time( NULL ) );
}

something.c:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
extern void nothing( void );
int main( )
{
    printf( "%lld\n", (long long)time( NULL ) );
    nothing( );
    return 0;
}

faketime.c:
#include <time.h>
time_t time( time_t * ptr )
{
    return 42;
}
```

Now, if I compile this code using the following:

```
gcc -fPIC -c -o nothing.lo nothing.c
gcc -shared -rdynamic -o libnothing.so nothing.lo
gcc -o something something.c faketime.c -Wl,-rpath=. -L. -lnothing
```

I get two different results on each of the environments upon which I attempt to run the executable.

Ubuntu 14.04 says the answer is "42/42" while Ubuntu 16.04 says the answer is "42/1464287587" (insert your current Unix timestamp).

I'm curious if this is a conscious change or whether I am doing something wrong here? I sort of assume the "new way" is actually more correct as it seems like a loophole for me to override a system call a library expects to make. However, maybe that's normal and maybe now this method of "linker substitution" is broken in the new compiler/linker?